# Display html tags within function that returns a value

Tags: php, html

I want to place a html codes into this variable. I've tried echo, print, and printf. However, print seems to be working but it returns a 1 that I don't want to see besides I can't place the words in the correct place.

Code:

```
if ($akTest) {
   $task = $akTest->getFullTask();
}

    return $task;
```

I want something like

```
if ($akTest) {
   $task = $akTest->getFullTask() . echo '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();
}
    return $task;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have the `echo` statement there?  If `getFullTask()` returns a string, just concatenate it with the string you want.  Not sure what you mean by "returns a 1" either.

Comment: I actually want to concatenate a function not a value so it has to be there, edited to explain more

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  How would you "concatenate a function"?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  But if "it has to be there" then, well, it's there.  So what's the problem?

Comment: If I do something like the example I want in the post I get an error "unexpected echo"

Comment: That's because you shouldn't have the `echo` statement there.  So remove it.

Comment: How I'd place an html code in there, then?

Comment: This isn't HTML, this is PHP.  What you have there is a string, and it's perfectly valid as it is.  Just remove the `echo` statement, exactly as the error message is telling you.

Comment: So there is no way that I can concatenate html codes with the php code in that case?

Comment: Why would you think that?  You can concatenate all the string values you want.  That random `echo` statement is causing an error.  ***Just.  Remove.  The.  Echo.  Statement.***

Comment: Then it'll output something like <p>Blabla</p> I want to put to output an html code so I can put there a class and style it a little bit.

Comment: How about you define what it currently outputs and what you want it to output and the difference between the two?  All you're trying to do is concatenate strings, which is simply done with the concatenation operator (`.`).

Comment: The current output: <p class"test">Texts</p> The output I want to get: Texts (has test as class)

Comment: You forgot the `=` in your HTML.  It should be `class="test"`.  The browser *might* automatically correct that for you, or it might not.  Output valid HTML.

Comment: you're not showing the full code. `return` suggest the use of a method somewhere and possibly a class. So how are you using that method right now? Btw, a method is another word for a function (in case you didn't know). We also don't know what `$akTest` is.

Comment: It's simply returning the value of that function, but I want to concatenate another function in, but putting a </br> between them or maybe a text with some css designs

Comment: well you can't echo in this `$task = $akTest->getFullTask() . echo '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();` and will throw an error about it. You can do `echo $task = $akTest->getFullTask() . '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();` though.

Comment: There is a return for that value at the bottom of the code if you realized.

Comment: well guess what `return` does? Here, read the manual for yourself http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php *"return returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.

If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file."*

Comment: @MohamedMahmoud: `"but I want to concatenate another function in, but putting a </br> between them or maybe a text with some css designs"` - And what exactly is stopping you from doing that?  You know how to concatenate strings.  So if you want to concatenate strings, then concatenate strings.  There are exactly *zero* problems here, why you're inventing problems that don't exist is beyond me.

Comment: Alright I have done what I wanted, but I stopped using return and used echo instead. Will it cause problems of whatsoever? Fred's answer was really helpful. However, thank you guys for trying to help me appreciate it.

Comment: and where is this function and what does it do? `getFullTask()`. Same thing for `getTime()`. Those aren't core php functions. Your question again; is too unclear. If you're not going to post full code, then you'll need to take it from here and what David posted. You're not only wasting other people's time, but "yours" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS this what you're looking for?

```
if ($akTest) {
   $task = '<p>' . $akTest->getFullTask() . '</p>' . getTime();
}
return $task;
```

If the $akTest->getFullTask function returns a string, it will be embedded into a string and be wrapped with paragraph html tags.

After reading your comments, you might also be looking for this:

```
if ($akTest) {
   $task_text = $akTest->getFullTask();
   $task_time = getTime();
   $task = $task_text . $task_time;
   echo $task_text . '<BR />' . $task_time;
}
return $task;
```

I added variables for the two function calls, so you didn't have to call them twice.  I could have just called the functions in both of the lines, as well.

To only echo the results to the browser and NOT return the value from the function, all you would need is this:

```
if ($akTest) {
   echo $akTest->getFullTask() . '< br/>' . getTime();
}
return;
```

Comment: Then it'll output something like <p>Blabla</p> I want to put to output an html code so I can put there a class and style it a little bit.

Comment: It will output a plain text with p tags on it. It won't be real html codes.

Comment: IT will wrap the task in a paragraph tag that you can style.  Are you trying to inject html into the task itself?  The code above will, when echoed into an html page, render as html.  Of course, You must be sure to properly cleanse the output from the getFullTask() function, but that wasn't part of the question so not addressed.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to return a string with html in it?  Or are you looking to send html to the browser at the time the function is called? - Updated my answer to reflect this possibility.

Comment: I want to send html to the browser at the time the function is called

Comment: You actually kinda got me, but the problem I want that text to be placed between the 2 functions for example: getFullTask = 'test'; $getTime = 'test2'; I want to do something like test </br> test2

Comment: Your code won't really work, because there is a return down there that returns the variable $task. and there is an echo that output the same result as the return statement does. However, I fixed it using an echo instead of return.

Comment: You never specified that you wanted to output a string instead of returning the value.  If you want to just do the echo and not return the data, then you should just change the "$task =" to "echo" in the your original code (after removing the extra echo statement).  My answers were based on you wanting to add the echo to your existing logic.  I'll update the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Another example added to the answer, replacing the returned text with an echo to the browser instead.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 1):

This is an invalid structure:

```
$task = $akTest->getFullTask() . echo '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();
```

The `echo` statement is entirely out of place.  If you're just concatenating strings, then just concatenate them:

```
$task = $akTest->getFullTask() . '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();
```

Comment: It's an html code I want to assign a class to it and so on, so it's not a plain string

Comment: @MohamedMahmoud: As far as PHP is concerned, HTML *is* "a plain string".  There's no difference.  Just output the HTML you want to the page and the browser will render it.

Comment: am wondering if all they're wanting to do is `echo $task = $akTest->getFullTask() . '<p> paragraph goes here</p>' . getTime();`. Question's way too unclear and I've told them that, along with this suggestion here. No idea as to what is supposed to do what.  @David

Comment: sorry to see you've been chased down a rabbit hole here David.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It happens.  I should learn to stay out of the PHP tag :-P

Comment: @David Nah, you're doing a good job David. I also noticed you got your gold for it too ;-) congrats.